# Make text inside svg centered using scss

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to put my text centered to triangle, I tried to make the position absolute and then top:0; right:0; left:0; bottom:0; nothing changed.

```html
<svg class="intro go" viewbox="0 0 200 86">
  <text text-anchor="start" x="10" y="30" class="text text-stroke" clip-path="url(#text1)">TEST</text>
  <text text-anchor="start" x="10" y="30" class="text text-stroke text-stroke-2" clip-path="url(#text1)">TEST</text>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="text1">
      <text text-anchor="start" x="10" y="30" class="text">TEST</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

here is my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePEdEZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by "centered to triangle"?

Did you mean centered to rectangle? If so:

Change the coordinates of the text from `x="10" y="30"` to `x="100" y="43"`.
Then set `text-anchor="start"` to `text-anchor="middle"`. And add `alignment-baseline="middle"` to your text. The text is now centered in the box.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1mLey8v4/

You could also set `alignment-baseline` and `text-anchor` by scss.

Looks cool btw!